# Android code to load image using picasso in non transparemt area

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I'm trying to load image using Picasso in attached image. But Picasso is using entire width and height of image.But I want to display only in first layer i.e non transparent area. Picasso is also using padding area around image which I don't want to include.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_multipleauthor_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_multiple_author"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_course_title_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

To load image

```
 Picasso.with(context)
    .load(authorModel.getImageUrl())
    .placeholder(resourceId)
    .error(resourceId)
    .transform(new CircleTransform())
    .into(authorImageView);
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to create a Customized Circular ImageView for this type of appearance. Have you created a cluster type view ? If yes then post it.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations